# Giant grey humanoid alien that mind controls earthlings

Tags: story-identification, novel

Paperback (I think) where humans (in the USA?) find a giant (grey?) alien in a tomb or crashed spaceship, circa 1950. The alien is hostile and can mind control everyone around it. It forces the humans to take it somewhere to build a rocket ship, or simply just enslave all of Earth.

Read in early '70s. Recollection of a picture with the alien on a giant rickshaw/platform being carried by hundreds of dying mind slaves. Perhaps it's killed by nukes in the end?

Comment: Some of this (grey mind-controlling alien found on Earth) sounds a lot like *World of Ptavvs* by Niven, but it's set in the future, and I don't recall the Thrint being carried on a platform.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this might be [*The Atlantic Abomination*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3278) (1960) by John Brunner.  Certainly the cover seems to be a good match:

[image: Cover of The Atlantic Abomination]

The setting is a near-future world (future from 1960; 1965 is noted as a date in the past) so it's not 1950s like suggested.  It is nevertheless a world based on that time with a strong USA and still-extant USSR, though the Cold War has eased somewhat.

A non-human intelligence is discovered in the wreckage of an unknown civilization by explorers deep in the Atlantic.  The alien wakes up and starts enslaving groups of people, initially causing ships to seem to vanish.  (Note that the alien is not humanoid, though it does have a grey skin.)

It can't enslave *everyone*, though, and the rest of the world fights back.  There's a big debate about deploying nuclear missiles against it, but ultimately that is done.  There is a kind of a stalemate, with human authorities not wanting to nuke its slaves, but the alien not being able to take over enough of humanity to conquer the whole world.  The alien holes up in a missile base near Jacksonville, and is finally revealed to be constructing some kind of "electro-gravitic" spaceship to escape but is taken out at the last minute by a nuclear missile.

A partial preview of the book is available at [Google Books](https://books.google.ca/books/about/The_Atlantic_Abomination.html?id=DMtaDwAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y).

Comment: That’s it 100%. The details of the plot from 40 years ago might be fuzzy... but that cover was etched in my memory.